# How to retrieve a specific record using the entity framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am storing three values in a three column field (user name ,the hashed password and the user type) and I want to try and retrieve them later .How do I go about .Right now my code for storing the data is like this

```
if (txtPassWord.Text.Length > 0)
{
   string strHashedPassword = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(txtPassWord.Text, "sha1");
}

objuser.username = txtEmailAddress.Text;
objuser.Password = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(txtPassWord.Text, "sha1"); ;
objuser.userRole = "member";

dbcontext.LicensingOrgInfoes.AddObject(obj);
dbcontext.SaveChanges();

dbcontextuser.Users.AddObject(objuser);
dbcontextuser.SaveChanges();
```

Now the question is how do I retrieved these stored values ?

Any inputs would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve the user object, or authenticate the user next time they try to log in?

Comment: I am trying to retrieve the user object so that I can authenticate the user the next time they log in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string myUsername = "MEMEMEME@here.com"

User me = dbcontext.Users.Single(u => u.username.ToLower() == myUsername.ToLower());
```

Assuming that usernames can not be reused.  But with what you have provided this is the best i can do for you.

Comment: Thanks ,that should work just fine since user names are supposed to be unique 

I am a little confused about what u=> stands for ?